# ¿Como oculto una columna entera de una tabla con javascript/jquery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Quiero mostrar/ocultar una columna de una tabla usando **javascript/jquery**.

Pulsando un botón muestre o oculte la columna entera. 
El nombre de la columna esta el el **TH** identificado por un id
Lo he logrado añadiendo un class a cada **TD** pero no me gusta esta solución, me gustaría lograrlo sin añadir tanto atributo class.

```js
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#ocultar").click(function(){
            $(".pais").hide();
        });
        $("#mostrar").click(function(){
            $('.pais').show();
        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
      <tr>
        <th>Company</th>
        <th>Contact</th>
        <th class="pais">Country</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
        <td>Maria Anders</td>
        <td class="pais">Germany</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
        <td>Francisco Chang</td>
        <td class="pais">Mexico</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Ernst Handel</td>
        <td>Roland Mendel</td>
        <td class="pais">Austria</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Island Trading</td>
        <td>Helen Bennett</td>
        <td class="pais">UK</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
        <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
        <td class="pais">Canada</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
        <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
        <td class="pais">Italy</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    
    <button id="ocultar">Hide</button>
    <button id="mostrar">Show</button>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sin tanto codigo se puede arreglar poniendo 1 botón, en vez de 2.

A menos que sea *estrictamente* necesario, creo que es mejor si solo tienes un botón, que haga `toggle` que vaya conmutando la visibilidad de la columna.

Para ello, seleccionamos la cabecera con `$(".pais")` y la ocultamos o mostramos con  `.toggle()`.

Para ocultar/mostrar las filas, podemos hacer un pequeño filtro como este:

```
$('td:nth-child(3)')
```

que significa: Coje los `td` que sean el tercer hijo de su padre. El padre es la fila `tr` y el tercer hijo es el `td` en la columna Pais.

y a ellos le aplicas el `toggle()` también.

Con esto te ahorras el poner la `class` a cada elemento que quieras ocultar.

```js
$("#boton").on("click", function(){

  $(".pais").toggle();
  $('td:nth-child(3)').toggle();

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
      <tr>
        <th>Company</th>
        <th>Contact</th>
        <th class="pais">Country</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
        <td>Maria Anders</td>
        <td>Germany</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
        <td>Francisco Chang</td>
        <td>Mexico</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Ernst Handel</td>
        <td>Roland Mendel</td>
        <td>Austria</td>
      </tr>
    </table>

    <button id="boton">Ocultar/Mostrar columna pais</button>
```

Comment: Al final me vale con : 
`$("#boton").on("click", function(){
  $('th:nth-child(3)').toggle();
  $('td:nth-child(3)').toggle();
});`
Quito la class y la id.

Answer (score 3):

Para ocultar con `JavaScript` , sin Jquery, se me ocurre que como ya tiene una clase que las identifica puede recurrir a estas para añadir una clase `hidden` , por ejemplo.

```js
let btnocultar = document.getElementById('ocultar');
let btnmostrar = document.getElementById('mostrar');
//buscamos las celdas con la clase pais
let celdas = document.querySelectorAll('.pais');

btnocultar.addEventListener('click',function(){
  //iteramos y añadimos la clase hidden
  celdas.forEach(function(el){
   el.classList.add('hidden');
  });
 
});

btnmostrar.addEventListener('click',function(){
//iteramos y removemos la clase hidden
  celdas.forEach(function(el){
   el.classList.remove('hidden');
  });
});
```

```css
.hidden{
  display: none;
 }
```

```html
<table class="mitabla">
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th class="pais">Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td class="pais">Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td class="pais">Mexico</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Ernst Handel</td>
    <td>Roland Mendel</td>
    <td class="pais">Austria</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Island Trading</td>
    <td>Helen Bennett</td>
    <td class="pais">UK</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
    <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
    <td class="pais">Canada</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
    <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
    <td class="pais">Italy</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<button id="ocultar">Ocultar columna pais</button>
<button id="mostrar">Mostrar columna pais</button>
```

Si también tiene en cuenta la modificación de `HTML` , podría eliminar las clases de cada `td` y solo añadir un `id` a la tabla además de remover un botón y tener solo `1` que funcione como un `toggle` , pero todo solo con solo `JavaScript`

```js
let btn = document.getElementById('ocultar');
let table = document.getElementById('mitabla');
btn.addEventListener('click',function(){
  //Iteramos las filas y accedemos a la tercera celda  [2]
  for (var i = 0, row; row = table.rows[i]; i++){
     row.cells[2].classList.toggle('hidden');
  }
});
```

```css
.hidden{ display: none; }
```

```html
<table id="mitabla">
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th >Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td >Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td >Mexico</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Ernst Handel</td>
    <td>Roland Mendel</td>
    <td >Austria</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Island Trading</td>
    <td>Helen Bennett</td>
    <td >UK</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
    <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
    <td >Canada</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
    <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
    <td >Italy</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<button id="ocultar">Mostrar/Ocultar</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

También puedes hacer lo siguiente desde CSS:

```
table > tr > td:nth-child(3), table > tr > th:nth-child(3) {
    display: none;
}
```

O tener una clase ocultar en CSS y por medio de javascript, añadir la clase:

```
<style>
    .ocultar {
        display: none;
    }
</style>

<script>
    $("#ocultar").click(function() {
        $("table > tr > td:nth-child(3), table > tr > th:nth-child(3)").addClass("ocultar");
    });
    $("#mostrar").click(function() {
        $(".ocultar").removeClass("ocultar");
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Disculpen, quería consultar lo siguiente respecto de algo parecido.
Si tengo este código citado de más arriba:

```
$("#boton").on("click", function(){

    $(".pais").toggle();
    $('td:nth-child(3)').toggle();

});
```

Cómo lo hago en caso de tener otra tabla al lado y oculte solo las columnas de una tabla y no de las 2...
Gracias.

Comment: Esto no provee una respuesta al problema, si tienes una nueva pregunta es mejor [formularla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask), con gusto te ayudaremos :D

Comment: ok. gracias. Ya lo hice.